# what is the equivalent sequelize query for this raw query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

SELECT offers.id FROM offers WHERE offers.user_id != '2' and offers.id not in (select notified_offers.offer_id from notified_offers where notified_offers.user_id = '2');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've associated `Offers` and `NotifiedOffers` models, and it is not a many-to-many association, you can do this:

```
Offers.findAll({
    attributes: ['id'],
    where: {
        user_id: {
            not: 2
        }
    },
    include: {
        model: NotifiedOffers,
        where: {
            user_id: {
                not: 2
            }
        },
        required: true
    }
});
```

Comment: how do i associate those two table? offer_id is a field in notified_offers table as the foreign key reference to offers(id)

Comment: I think this `NotifiedOffers.belongsTo(Offers,{foreignKey:'offer_id'})` would work for you, but you can get more info here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/